# How to tell if a Gtk.Widget is a Gtk.Container?

Tags: gtk, ada

I am using GTKAda to handle a callback which returns an "access Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record'Class". How can I find out if this Widget is a Gtk.Container or not?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

```ada
if Widget in Gtk_Container_Record'Class then
   ...
```